# Get values from two rows and convert to variables

Tags: perl, sed, awk, grep

I have values from two rows, want to get all values and make them to variables.

Output is from emc storage:

```
Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 0
State:                   Enabled

Bus 0 Enclosure 0  Disk 1
State:                   Enabled
```

Expected result:

```
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:0|State:Enabled
```

Or just need somebody to give me direction how to get the last row ...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try this awk:

```
$ awk '/^Bus/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s:%s|", $i,$(i+1)}/^State/{printf "%s%s\n", $1, $2}' file
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:0|State:Enabled
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:1|State:Enabled
```

To handle multiple words in the last field, you can do:

```
$ awk '/^Bus/{for(i=1;i<=NF;i+=2) printf "%s:%s|", $i,$(i+1)}/^State/{printf "%s", $1; for (i=2;i<=NF;i++) printf "%s ", $i; print ""}' file
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:0|State:Enabled 
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:1|State:hot space
```

Comment: Probably is possible to extend the script if for example latest word is not Enabled and for ex.: Hot Spare, then we should see only "Hot". How can improve to get everything after the last column?

Answer (score 3):

This might work for you (GNU sed):

```
sed '/^Bus/!d;N;s/[0-9]\+/:&|/g;s/\s//g' file
```

To get only the last row:

```
sed '/^Bus/{N;h};$!d;x;s/[0-9]\+/:&|/g;s/\s//g' file
```

Answer (score 2):

```
perl -00anE 's/:// for @F; say join "|", map { $_%2 ? () : "$F[$_]:$F[$_+1]" } 0..$#F' file
```

output

```
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:0|State:Enabled
Bus:0|Enclosure:0|Disk:1|State:Enabled
```

Answer (score 1):

With `GNU awk` you could do:

```
$ awk 'NR>1{$6=$6$7;NF--;print RS,$0}' RS='Bus' OFS='|' file
Bus|0|Enclosure|0|Disk|0|State:Enabled
Bus|0|Enclosure|0|Disk|1|State:Enabled
```

And for the last row only:

```
$ awk 'END{$6=$6$7;NF--;print RS,$0}' RS='Bus' OFS='|' file
Bus|0|Enclosure|0|Disk|1|State:Enabled
```